# OpenType's Chained Contexts Substitution: what is semantics?

Tags: opentype

I'm struggling to understand the semantics of Chained Contexts Substitutions.

In a feature file of an OpenType font, I have (simplified):

```
@MarkSet0=[\A \D];
@MarkSet1=[\A \B];

lookup Lookup0 {
  lookupflag UseMarkFilteringSet @MarkSet0;
    sub \A \D by \C;
} Lookup0;

lookup Lookup1 {
  lookupflag 0;
    sub \B \B by \E;
} Lookup1;

lookup ligaLookup2 {
  lookupflag UseMarkFilteringSet @MarkSet1;
    sub [\A]'lookup Lookup0 [\B]'lookup Lookup1;
} ligaLookup2;
```

(Only ligaLookup2 belongs to a feature.)

I would expect application of both substitution rules in Lookup0 and Lookup1, to get:

```
ABBD -> CE
```

But the behaviour I see in OpenType tools (e.g. Crowbar) and in browsers is:

```
ABBD -> CBB
ABBG -> AEG
```

Somehow the substitution in Lookup0 that reaches over the BB prevents Lookup1 from changing those BB.

Can this be explained by general rules defining the semantics of Chained Context Substitutions?

Comment: I'm very interested in providing an answer to your question, but it isn't simply due to general semantics of Chained Context Substitutions. It probably involves interaction between what OpenType defines and what AFDKO compiles. Can you provide a compiled font using these feature file rules so I can look at the data that got generated? (A minimal font would be preferable.)

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be explained by general rules defining the semantics of Chained Context Substitutions?

Behaviour could be impacted by what data is compiled by the font tool you've used, or how particular layout engines implement an interpretation of the OpenType specification. I can comment on the semantics intended by the OpenType spec.

> **Aside:** Your question called out "Chained Context Substitutions". The OpenType GSUB table spec describes [Contextual substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gsub#lookuptype-5-contextual-substitution-subtable) and [Chained contexts substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/gsub#lookuptype-6-chained-contexts-substitution-subtable). The difference between these is that the latter has "chained" contexts—preceding ("backtrack") and following ("lookahead") sequences that need to match for actions to be applied but that otherwise do not participate in any way in the actions. The semantics of backtrack and lookahead contexts are not significant for your question. The parts that could be relevant are the semantics of contextual substitution (common to both) or the effects of mark filtering.

Based on the feature file syntax in your example, I'm assuming you're using Adobe's [Font Development Kit for OpenType](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/afdko). I checked with an Adobe contact for that tool who confirmed the GSUB table data your example would generate, and it matched what I would have expected.

But the display results you mentioned, `ABBD -> CBB`, as well as what you expected, `ABBD -> CE`, are both different from what I would have expected based on the OT spec, and are different from what my Adobe contact observed after trying to reproduce the result building a font with the feature file rules you gave. Rather, what I expected, and what he observed, is `ABBD -> AED`.

Let me explain why I expect `ABBD -> AED`.

You have a parent lookup, ligaLookup2, that specifies a mark filtering set, MarkSet1 (= {A, B}); then two nested lookups: Lookup0 which specifies a different mark filtering set (MarkSet0 = {A, D}), and Lookup1 which doesn't specify any mark filtering. The mark filtering applied to the parent lookup, ligaLookup2, would be used to determine if the glyph sequence in the text data matches the input sequence specified for the lookup, and what the input sequence is that gets processed by the nested lookups. Since MarkSet1 = {A,B}, the matched input sequence is `ABB`. When the sequence of nested actions are processed, I would expect them to be operating on that sequence, `ABB`.

The first nested action is Lookup0. It specifies mark filtering using MarkSet0, {A, D}, so given the sequence `ABB` it would filter out the `B`s, leaving a sequence of just `A`. Lookup0 wants to act on a sequence `AD`, but that doesn't match. So the first nested action becomes a no-op.

The second nested action is Lookup1. After the first nested action has been evaluated, the interim glyph sequence is (still) `ABB`. The data compiled into the font by AFDKO specifies that the action should apply starting at sequence index 1 (base 0); so Lookup1 will be operating on the sub-sequence `BB`. That matches, and so the substitution `BB -> E` would occur. The result after the section nested action is that `ABB` has been transformed into `AE`.

Putting that back into the fuller context, `ABBD` would be transformed into `AED`.

Again, it's unclear why you might have observed `ABBD -> CBB`. To explore further, it would be necessary to examine actual font data that reproduces that behaviour.

Comment: Much obliged for the help. If I understand correctly, any "descendant" lookups should only be able to operate on the marks that are in the filter set of the "ancestor" lookups. I obtained the TTF file by compiling a TTX file using fontTools. The TTF file is here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14mqpt1Vn0lVA3vQ8V7ID2EW9rFN6wjid/view?usp=sharing).